# Optimizing query to use the primary key instead of another index

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to optimize the execution of a MYSQL query that joins two tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `CPP` (
  `RecordEntryType` varchar(7) NOT NULL default '',
  `PositionNumber` mediumint(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `FundId` smallint(6) default NULL,
  `QuantityHeld` decimal(14,2) default NULL,
  `MarketValue` decimal(14,2) default NULL,
  `PeriodBeginDate` date default NULL,
  `PeriodEndDate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`PositionNumber`,`PeriodEndDate`,`RecordEntryType`),
  KEY `Index1` (`FundId`,`PeriodBeginDate`,`PeriodEndDate`),
  KEY `FundId_idx` (`FundId`),
  KEY `PeriodBeginDate_idx` (`PeriodBeginDate`),
  KEY `PeriodEndDate_idx` (`PeriodEndDate`),
  KEY `PositionNumber_id` (`PositionNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `classification_entity_map` (
  `entity_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `entity_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `scheme_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class_id` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`entity_id`,`entity_type`,`scheme_id`),
  KEY `fk_classification_entity_map_1` (`scheme_id`),
  KEY `fk_class` (`class_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_class` FOREIGN KEY (`class_id`) REFERENCES `classification_hierarchy` (`external_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_scheme` FOREIGN KEY (`scheme_id`) REFERENCES `classification_schemes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

select cpp.*, cem.class_id from cpp
LEFT JOIN classification_entity_map cem 
ON cem.entity_id = cpp.PositionNumber and cem.entity_type = 'Security'
AND cem.scheme_id = 9901
WHERE cpp.RecordEntryType = 'CURRENT'
AND ( cpp.MarketValue != 0 OR cpp.QuantityHeld != 0 )
AND FundId = 28
AND cpp.PeriodEndDate = '2013-09-30';
```

The issue is that the query takes longer than expected in mysql workbench (9.4 secs) as it is using the fk_classification_entity_map_1 index rather than the primary index on classification_entity_map table.  cpp has 626,648 rows and cem has 63,487 rows.

I suspect that the issue has to do with the datatypes of cem.entity_id & cpp.PositionNumber but I am not sure as they cannot be changed.  Please help.  I can upload the explain output if that is helpful.

More Info: Changing the join to convert(cpp.PositionNumber, char(32)) as below does not help as the time goes up to 10 secs:

```
ON cem.entity_id = convert(cpp.PositionNumber, char(32)) and cem.entity_type =   'Security'
AND cem.scheme_id = 9901
```

The explain output for the query without convert is below and sees the PRIMARY as possible (but not in the query with convert):

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  cpp index_merge Index1,FundId_idx,PeriodEndDate_idx FundId_idx,PeriodEndDate_idx    3,3     402 Using intersect(FundId_idx,PeriodEndDate_idx); Using where
1   SIMPLE  cem ref PRIMARY,fk_classification_entity_map_1  fk_classification_entity_map_1  4   const   24100
```

Comment: And the explain is always helpful? iám wondering if the MySQL optimizer is seeing the primary key off table classification_entity_map as an possible key..

Comment: Your problem is indeed in the ON clause you are joining mixed types.. cem.entity_id varchar(32) vs cpp.PositionNumber mediumint(9) you can't never speed it up like this.. and not with an convert

Comment: Can you change the order of the columns in the primary key? If you change it to `(entity_type, scheme_id, entity_id)`, or change `fk_classification_entity_map_1` to `(scheme_id, entity_type)`, I think it should help, because then you can use one of these indexes for two of the columns you're testing in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Interestingly, Toad for MySQL uses the primary key for the convert query but not for the plain query.  Why would the client tool matter?

Comment: Doing the `convert()` in the JOIN isn't going to help.  You need both columns to be of the same type if MySQL is to take advantage of the indexes.